# Zend_Services_Twitter, change the API Source name

Tags: php, zend-framework, twitter

I am sending tweets to Twitter via Zend_Service_Twitter.

The tweets appear with a note "via API". I want to set the API Source with a different name, is there already a functionality within the Zend Framework to change it?

Or do I need to subclass to get this functionality?

Thanks!

Comment: Need to wait a week or so until Zend_Service_Twitter supports OAuth. Subscribe to fw-general@ to get the updates.

Comment: hey till, you seem to be everywhere too! favo aka mario aka bill :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter is dropping the Source parameter since they're going to drop basic auth support in a few weeks as well, replacing it with OAuth which has the Source stuff built in.  Like the commenter says, watch the Zend_Service_Twitter class in the coming weeks for a version that supports OAuth.

Answer (score 1):

Please note, if you want to change the "Source" you have to use Oauth for authentication.

[Twitter OAuth and Source](http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-api-announce/browse_thread/thread/ce57405a08483877/077165f18da99ff7?lnk=raot&pli=1)